# Ruby block code in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

The code below is working

```
-@items.each do |item|
 %tr
  %td
   =item.quantity
   times
  %td= item.product.title
 end
```

However I want to use `{ }` instead of `do ... end`. Is it possible?

```
-@items.each { |item|
 %tr
  %td
   =item.quantity
   times
  %td= item.product.title
 }
```

For some reason it throws an exception. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can't. That's now how HAML works.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your working example the `end` line is being treated as raw text, and will be included in your output. This works because you effectively don’t have an `end` keyword. If you change this line to `- end` — i.e. add the hyphen (and make sure you’ve got your indentation correct) — you’ll see an error like:

```
Syntax error on line 9: You don't need to use "- end" in Haml. Un-indent to close a block:
- if foo?
  %strong Foo!
- else
  Not foo.
%p This line is un-indented, so it isn't part of the "if" block
```

Note that Haml doesn’t always disallow `end` keywords, only `end` by itself. You can use them with statement modifiers, e.g.:

```
- @things.each do |thing|
  %p= thing.to_s
-end unless @dont_show_things
```

or if you want to make use of the result of the block:

```
= @things.map do |thing|
  - do_something_with(thing)
-end.join(",")
```

As for using `{}`, you can’t. When Haml compiles the template to Ruby the [hardcoded string `end` is added to close any blocks as needed](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/3.1.6/lib/haml/compiler.rb#L74). It could be possible to modify Haml to be able to use `do..end` or `{}`, but the extra complexity probably isn’t worth it. This way is a better fit with the common Ruby idiom of using `do...end` for multiline blocks, and `{}` for single line ones.

If you need to use `{}` because of some issue with operator precedence it might be a sign to create a helper method. Your Haml templates (or templates in any language) aren’t the best place for complex logic, it’s best to move it into real Ruby files.

Comment: For anyone still using haml :), I was trying to get map/join(",") working to output some markup formatted within the map block and it wasn't working as expected. To get things working I had to do: https://gist.github.com/bradley/21a7b087d5b2756dc0f90af9cecce780

Answer (score 5):

You DO NOT put any `end` in HAML. The indentation is semantic. Your code should therefore be :

```
- @items.each do |item|
  %tr
    %td
      = item.quantity
      times
    %td= item.product.title
```

EDIT: Using `{` will throw a syntax error.

Comment: I'm asking about `{}` but about `do ... end`.

Comment: I know that using `end` is redundant. But it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error because it's considered as text. Evaluating your code will actually display "end" in the HTML code.

Comment: I don't know why this was voted down, the advice is correct. I've voted it up.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add complex ruby code, you can use the ruby syntax,

```
:ruby
  x = case a
  when 2
     "two"
  when 3
     "three"
  end
```